# Why does the array push an empty array into another?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Why is the value of `array2` `[[], [], [], [], []]` at the end of the loop?

```js
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  array1.push(i);
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    //console.log(array1);
    array2.push(array1);
    array1.length = 0;
  };
};
console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```

Can anyone explain, what's going on in this code?

Comment: Your code explicitly sets the `.length` of `array1` to zero. Pushing the array into another array does **not** make a copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays in JavaScript are mutable structures. `array1` is getting emptied out each time by assigning `0` to `length`. Theres only 5 even numbers between 1 and 10 (namely: 2, 4, 6, 8, 10), so `array2` has 5 references to `array1` in it.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of `array1.length = 0;`.

You are pointing the same array reference and setting it to empty.

So technically you are pushing a new empty array for every even number in the iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have already explained what's going on, here's what to do to get what you expected:

```js
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  array1.push(i);
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    //console.log(array1);
    array2.push([...array1]);
    array1.length = 0;
  };
};
console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```

You can simply use a new ECMAScript feature called **array destructuring** `[...arr]` (destructuring into a new array), which creates a shallow copy of the array it is applied on.

Comment: Thank you so much, I actually wanted to know too how can get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you push an array / object variable, you are storing the reference, not the value. Making array1 length equals to 0 as you know you are deleting array1 values, and this cause the result you are seeing for array2.

If you want to have the behaviour you expect you can create a new array before each push like:

```
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  array1.push(i);
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    array2.push(Array.from(array1));
    array1.length = 0;
  };
};
// []
console.log(array1);
// [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ], [ 5, 6 ], [ 7, 8 ], [ 9, 10 ] ]
console.log(array2);
```